# Find the max value of node in a tree

Tags: haskell, binary-tree

I have a problem.

I have to implement a function `maxT` in Haskell which returns the maximum value of a node from a binary tree.

```
data Tree a = Leaf a | Node (Tree a) a (Tree a)
```

This is given. What should I do next?

```
maxT :: (Tree Integer) -> Integer
maxT (Leaf a) = a
maxT (Node l a r) = max a (max (maxT l) (maxT r))
```

Is this right?

Comment: It's not the most perfect implementation, but it looks to me like it should work. Can you elaborate on what you think is wrong with it?

Comment: You might want to generalize the type of it to `maxT :: Ord a => Tree a -> a`, but other than that it looks fine.

Comment: Have you tried testing it? Try this: `maxT (Node (Node (Leaf 1) 5 (Leaf (-4))) 2 (Node (Leaf 6) 2 (Leaf 4)))`

Comment: It works. You don't have a problem!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's see how hard this is to *prove* correct. Why? Because it's a great way to analyze programs for errors. Especially recursive ones. We'll technically use induction, but it isn't so complex. The key is to realize that `maxT t` must always be the largest value in the tree `t`—this declaration, "`maxT t` must always be the largest value in the tree `t`" is called an invariant and we'll try to prove it.

First, let's assume `t` is a `Leaf`. In this case, you've defined `maxT (Leaf a) = a` and since there are literally *no other values* in this tree, `a` *must* be the largest. Thus, `maxT` upholds our invariant when passed a `Leaf`. This is the "base case".

---

Now we'll consider what happens when we let `t = Node (Leaf a) b (Leaf c)` for some `Integer`s `a`, `b`, and `c`. This is a height-1 tree and forms what you might call an "example case" for induction. Let's try out `maxT` and see if the invariant holds.

```
maxT t 
===
maxT (Node (Leaf a) b (Leaf c))
===
max b (max (maxT (Leaf a)) (maxT (Leaf c)))
```

at this point we'll use our base-case step and say that since the only applications of `maxT` in this expression are on `Leaf`s then each one must uphold our invariant. This is kind of dumb, but that's because it's just an example case. We'll see the more general pattern later.

For now, let's evaluate our `maxT (Leaf _)` bits knowing that the result is the maximal value in each particular left- or right-subtree.

```
===
max b (max a c)
```

Now, I don't much want to dive into the definition of `max`, but based on its name I'm happy to assume that `max a b` returns value that is maximal between `a` and `b`. We could pick our way through the details here, but it's clear that `max b (max a c)` has been given all the relevant information about our `Node` for computing the maximum of the entire height-1 tree. I'd call this a successful proof that `maxT` works for both height-0 and height-1 trees (`Leaf`s and `Node`s containing only `Leaf`s).

The next step is to generalize this example case.

---

So let's apply that same pattern generalizing on the height of the tree. We'll ask what happens if we fix some number, `n`, and assume that `maxT t` upholds our invariant for all `t` of height `n` or less. This is a little bizarre—we have only shown this works for `n = 0` and `n = 1`. It'll be clear why this works a little later.

So what does that assumption do for us? Well, let's take any two `Tree`s of height `n` or less (call them `l` and `r`), any integer `x`, and combine them to form a new tree `t = Node x l r`. What happens when we do `maxT t`?

```
maxT t
===
maxT (Node x l r)
===
max x (max (maxT l) (maxT r))
```

and we know, per our assumption, that `maxT l` and `maxT r` uphold our invariant. Then the chain of `max`es continues to uphold our invariant now for a tree `t` that's height-`(n+1)`. Furthermore (and this is really important) our process of assembling new `Tree`s is general—we can make *any* height-`(n+1)` tree in this method. This means that `maxT` works for any height-`(n+1)` tree.

---

Induction time! We now know that if we pick an `n` and believe (for some reason) that `maxT` works for any height-`n` tree, then it immediately must work for any height-`(n+1)` tree. Let's pick `n = 0`. We know by the "base case" that `maxT` works for `Leaf`s, so suddenly we know that `maxT` works for height-`1` trees. This was our "example case". Now, given that knowledge, we can immediately see `maxT` works for height-`2` trees. And then height-`3` trees. And then height-`4`. And so on and on and on.

This completes a proof* that `maxT` is correct.

*I have to leave a few caveats. We didn't really do the fiddly details to show that the `max` chains work out, though it makes sense. I also didn't really prove that the induction step works—what if there were more ways to make a height-`(n+1)` tree than just using `Node` on height-`n` or lesser trees? The more powerful way is to "break apart" a height-`n` tree, but that's a little harder to see, I think. Finally, we would want to really think hard about what happens if we send in `maxT (Leaf undefined)` or other pathological values like that. These arise in Haskell because it's a (turing-complete) computer language instead of pure math. Honestly, these little bits don't change a whole lot for your situation, though.